# Table is rendered but dataTables will not modify existing HTML table in Flask

Tags: flask, datatables

Below I have provided a minimum working example of my Flask app that uses dataTable.JS to modify an existing HTML table. In cross-comparing with [current examples online](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/beautiful-interactive-tables-for-your-flask-templates), I think this is due to required libraries not being loaded properly and/or that it cannot find the data.

Guidance is greatly appreciated!

**HTML (base.html)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.11.5/af-2.3.7/b-2.2.2/fc-4.0.2/fh-3.2.2/sc-2.0.5/sl-1.3.4/datatables.min.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="logo"></h1>
        <strong><nav>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('map') }}">Entity Map</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav></strong>
          <div class = "logoimg">
              <img src="{{ url_for('static',filename='images/GENERIC_PDE_PageCard.png') }}" width="10%">
          </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.11.5/af-2.3.7/b-2.2.2/fc-4.0.2/fh-3.2.2/sc-2.0.5/sl-1.3.4/datatables.min.js"></script>
  {% block scripts %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**HTML(home.html)**

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{%  block content %}
<div class = "home">
    <h3>OCFY Entity Database</h3>
    <h4>Purpose</h4>
    <p>Purpose This application is designed for performing custom queries to a database containing information about private and non-public entities who are serving school-aged children and youth in the Commonwealth of Pennsylvania. Sites in this database include private or non-public licensed schools, as well as non-public entities such as residential and juvenile justice institutions.</p>
    <h4>How to Search</h4>
    <p>The database provides information at the site-level, as well as by several higher-order aggregates, including region, county, city, type of service, PDE Educational Entity and DHS Entity.
        Use the drop-down filters within to perform a custom query that automatically displays in the table on the next tab. Selecting one or more values fromm the filters will automatically remove irrelevant values from the rest of the filters. You can also use the filters in any order. They will still show only relevant options.
        The search function at the top right of the table accepts words and/or whole numbers. The search function looks across all columns for all entities in the database and displays every entity with a column containing the number and/or word that was typed.
        Use the first drop down box to select multiple fields from the database. Your choices will be displayed automatically in the table. The application defaults to showing several key fields. Use backspace within the search box to remove fields from the table.</p>
</div>
    <br>
    <div class = "homecontent">
        <div class = "sidebar">
            <h4>Select Fields from Database</h4>
        </div>
        <div  class = "tablecontainer">
            <table id="entity_table" class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>DHS Entity Name</th>
                        <th>DHS Legal Name</th>
                        <th>Full Address</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Test1</td>
                        <td>Test2</td>
                        <td>Test3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Test1</td>
                        <td>Test2</td>
                        <td>Test3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Test1</td>
                        <td>Test2</td>
                        <td>Test3</td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
{%  endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#entity_table').dataTable();
    });
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

**CSS (main.css)**

```html
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #444;
}
/*
 * Formatting the header area
 */
header {
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 3px #d0d1d3; /* offset x, offset y, blur radius */
  background-color: #002060;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: .9;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

div.container {
  scroll-behavior: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

div.logoimg{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
}

/*
 * Formatting the container contents
 */
.container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div.homecontent{
  width: 1200px;
}

div.tablecontainer {
  float: right;
  width: 850px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

div.sidebar {
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 3px #d0d1d3;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #F3F4F5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
          border-radius: 6px;
}

div.home {
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 3px #d0d1d3;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #F3F4F5;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
          border-radius: 6px;
}
div.map {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #F3F4F5;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
          border-radius: 6px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: #999;
}
.menu {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
.menu li {
  display: inline;
}
.menu li + li {
  margin-left: 35px;
}
.menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**App:**

```html
from flask import Flask, render_template
ocyf = Flask(__name__)

@ocyf.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@ocyf.route('/map/')
def map():
    return render_template("map.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ocyf.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use thead and tbody tags on your table.

```
<table id="entity_table" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>DHS Entity Name</th>
            <th>DHS Legal Name</th>
            <th>Full Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Test1</td>
            <td>Test2</td>
            <td>Test3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test1</td>
            <td>Test2</td>
            <td>Test3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test1</td>
            <td>Test2</td>
            <td>Test3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```